# Is having a repository on GitHub considered distribution?

Tags: apache-2.0, github, distribution

### TL;DR

Is having a repository on GitHub considered *distribution* in the sense of a license?

### Description

I have some repositories on GitHub. Now I modified a file for a project. The file was licensed under Apache 2.

The project is for an online course from Udacity to learn Android development.

My understanding is the following. If I distribute the file then I have to comply with the license in the sense that I have to:

1. include the copyright
2. include the license
3. state the changes
4. include a notice

### Question

Now my thinking is since I keep my repository public on GitHub, is it considered distribution, and thus I have to state the changes and include notices, etc. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is considered redistribution. If not what would?

Comment: What if I said I am only keeping it on GitHub for my own use and benefit during the coursework; because public GitHub is free (and a cloud back).

Comment: Then you would be violating the Github terms of service (See "LIcense Grant to Other Users, paragraph 5)

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I thought that was only a right to fork? It didn't give any other rights as far as I understand (but then I've never really read it) :P

Comment: Well, if I fork a repository then I've received a complete copy of the project; that amounts to distribution, which was the question.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I think that answers my questions. I understand the paragraph 5 you mentioned is valid and true even if I adopt a license that states otherwise: e.g. "you are only allowed to fork if you don't keep it in a private repository".